# scroll to and reveal div on click - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, scroll, show-hide

I can do the above mentioned, but as I'm new to jquery I wondered if anyone could show me a 'more efficient' solution to the problem.

Basically, when a radio is clicked, it will reveal and scroll to a div.

```
$("input:radio[name='one']").click(function() {      
  $('table.one').fadeIn(800); 
  $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$('table.one').position().top}, 'slow');
});

$("input:radio[name='two']").click(function() {      
  $('table.two').fadeIn(800); 
  $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$('table.two').position().top}, 'slow');
});

$("input:radio[name='three']").click(function() {      
  $('table.three').fadeIn(800); 
  $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$('table.three').position().top}, 'slow');
});

<table class="one" style="display: none;"> ...
```

I've used the same script three times, what is the best way of scripting this?
Many thanks :-)

Comment: I think this question may be off-topic because this question belongs on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make the code dryer by getting the target table from the input thats been clicked by giving it a data attribute such as `<input type='radio' data-table='one' />`

```
$("input:radio").click(function() {   
  var table = 'table.' + $(this).attr('data-table');   
  $('' + table).fadeIn(800); 
  $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:$('' + table).position().top}, 'slow');
});
```

There are several other ways you can get the table fro the input though, such as a class.